# Mean line between two polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, line

I have two separate polygons A and B in ArcMap. Which tool I have to use in order to find the mean line between them?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  I think you should use the [edit] button beneath your question to include a picture of two such polygons and what you think the mean line between them should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) convert your polygon vertices to point

2) use the tool "create thiessen polygons"

3) use "update" with the "no boundary" option to update your thiessen polygons with the initial polygons (alternatively, extract polygon attributes with spatial join then dissolve based on polygon ID's)

4) use "feature to line" to create a line